# Changing Jan to Dec YTD date functions to run April to March

Tags: sql, sql-date-functions

I have 7 slightly different date functions that work out YTD bookings [Jan to Dec] based on created & arrival dates [please see below]. My question is this, how do I easily change these to accommodate for an April to March Financial Year instead of January to December?

```
1.   --CREATED BY YEAR--LAST YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *CREATED DATE*)---
COUNT(CASE WHEN (CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE)>=CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,DATEADD(m,-12,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR)+'-01-01') AND (CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE)<DATEADD(m,-12,GETDATE())) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END) AS [LastYearToDateBookingsCreated]

2. --CREATED BY YEAR--THIS YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *CREATED DATE*)---
COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedYear=DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END) AS [ThisYearToDateBookingsCreated]

3. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--LAST YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *ARRIVAL DATE*, NOT CREATED DATE)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, - 12, GETDATE())) AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= DATEADD(m, - 12, GETDATE())) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [LastYearToDateBookings]

4. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--THIS YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (arrivals this year onward, with any createdate up to today)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= GETDATE()) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [YearToDateBookings]

5. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--NEXT YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (arrivals next year, with any createdate up to today)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) + 1 AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= GETDATE()) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [NextYearToDateBookings]

6. --ARRIVALS ANYTIME THIS YEAR THAT WERE CREATED UP TO TODAY'S DATE LAST YEAR--
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) AND (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())-1 AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE)<=CAST(DATEADD(d,-364,GETDATE()) AS DATE))) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS ThisYearToDateBookingsByArrivalsBookedLastYear

7. --ARRIVALS ANYTIME NEXT YEAR THAT WERE CREATED UP TO TODAY'S DATE THIS YEAR---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())+1 AND (DATEPART(yyyy, MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS NextYearToDateBookingsByArrivalsBookedThisYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you I think.

```
 BEGIN
DECLARE @LASTENDDATE DATE
DECLARE @LASTSTARTDATE DATE
DECLARE @THISENDDATE DATE
DECLARE @THISSTARTDATE DATE
DECLARE @NEXTENDDATE DATE
DECLARE @NEXTSTARTDATE DATE

-- Last Financial Year
SELECT @LASTENDDATE = DATEADD(dd,-365,(DATEPART(year, GETDATE())||'0331'))
SELECT @LASTSTARTDATE = DATEADD(dd,-364,@LASTENDDATE)

-- This Financial Year
SELECT @THISENDDATE = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())||'0331'
SELECT @THISSTARTDATE = DATEADD(dd,-364,@THISENDDATE)

-- Next Financial Year
SELECT @NEXTENDDATE =  DATEADD(dd,+366,(DATEPART(year, GETDATE())||'0331'))
SELECT @NEXTSTARTDATE = DATEADD(dd,-365,@NEXTENDDATE)

1.   --CREATED BY YEAR--LAST YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *CREATED DATE*)---
COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) BETWEEN @THISSTARTDATE AND @THISENDDATE  THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END) AS [LastYearToDateBookingsCreated]

2. --CREATED BY YEAR--THIS YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *CREATED DATE*)---
COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate BETWEEN @THISSTARTDATE AND GETDATE() THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END) AS [ThisYearToDateBookingsCreated]

3. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--LAST YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (BASED ON *ARRIVAL DATE*, NOT CREATED DATE)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate BETWEEN @LASTSTARTDATE AND @LASTENDDATE AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= DATEADD(m, - 12, GETDATE()) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [LastYearToDateBookings]

4. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--THIS YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (arrivals this year onward, with any createdate up to today)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate BETWEEN @THISSTARTDATE AND @THISENDDATE AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= GETDATE() THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [YearToDateBookings]

5. --ARRIVALS BY YEAR--NEXT YEAR - UP TO TODAY'S DATE (arrivals next year, with any createdate up to today)---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate BETWEEN @NEXTSTARTDATE AND @NEXTENDDATE AND CAST(MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= GETDATE() THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS [NextYearToDateBookings]

6. --ARRIVALS ANYTIME THIS YEAR THAT WERE CREATED UP TO TODAY'S DATE LAST YEAR--
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate BETWEEN @THISSTARTDATE AND @THISENDDATE AND MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate BETWEEN @LASTSTARTDATE AND DATEADD(dd,-365,GETDATE()) THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS ThisYearToDateBookingsByArrivalsBookedLastYear

7. --ARRIVALS ANYTIME NEXT YEAR THAT WERE CREATED UP TO TODAY'S DATE THIS YEAR---
ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.ArrivalDate BETWEEN @NEXTSTARTDATE AND @NEXTENDDATE AND MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.CreatedDate BETWEEN @THISSTARTDATE AND GETDATE() THEN MASTER_VIEW_TradingReports.HolidayCost END), 0) AS NextYearToDateBookingsByArrivalsBookedThisYear

END
```

Comment: Hi Kevin Thanks for getting back to me. I tried running the above and got the following errors. Managed to fix the first 3 by removing one of the '|', but it seems to be throwing an error on the first COUNT..any ideas what could be causing it?

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '|'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '|'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near '|'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near 'COUNT'.

Comment: Try it again now, I had a couple of brackets too many in the query.  Sorry I do not have a DB in front of me to test the syntax.

Comment: I'm experiencing the following error:-
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
I'm guessing it has something to do with GETDATE())||'0331')) ?

Comment: Try replacing the concatenate double pipe || with the plus sign +.  Like this for example... DATEADD(dd,-365,(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()+'0331'))

Comment: Eventually figured it out :) Should be...

DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())-1)+'-03-31'))
DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))+'-03-31'))
DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())+1)+'-03-31'))

Thank you for all your help. Much appreciated.